# JQuery UI Resizable: Prevent smaller size than content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI resizable to be able to resize the 'wrapper' class in the sample below. How can I prevent resizable from resizing the wrapper to be smaller than the content in the sample below? I don't want to use overflow: hidden though.

Thanks!

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form class="content">
        <!-- form elements -->
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="text"/>
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can you define a minimal Width to your resizable element?

Have a look here
http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-minWidth

Example http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/resizable/max-min.html

or try to calculate that minimal.

Comment: Great, I think the minWidth, minHeight options of resizable will work.